# Shaders compile and link without error, but texture still not visible

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es-2.0

I would like to display a very simple texture on a GLSurfaceView which covers the whole viewport. I have a perfectly running version in WebGL, but for some reason my android code is not displaying my texture (at all).

Tried to hard code the color in the fragment shader, to ignore the texture, but nothing changed ... maybe the shaders are not even being applied at all?

```
    private fun loadShader(shaderType: Int, source: String): Int {
        var shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType)
        if (shader != 0) {
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source)
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader)
            val compiled = IntArray(1)
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0)
            if (compiled[0] == 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader $shaderType:")
                Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader))
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader)
                shader = 0
            } else{
                Log.e(TAG, "Shader $shaderType compiled!")
                Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader))
            }
        }
        return shader
    }

    private fun createProgram(vertexSource: String, fragmentSource: String): Int {
        val vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource)
        if (vertexShader == 0) {
            return 0
        }
        val pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource)
        if (pixelShader == 0) {
            return 0
        }

        var program = GLES20.glCreateProgram()
        if (program != 0) {
            GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader)
            checkGlError("glAttachShader")
            GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader)
            checkGlError("glAttachShader")
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(program)
            val linkStatus = IntArray(1)
            GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0)
            if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ")
                Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program))
                GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program)
                program = 0
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Shader Program Linked!")
            }
        }
        return program
    }

    private fun checkGlError(op: String) {
        val error: Int = GLES20.glGetError()
        while (error  != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.e(TAG, "$op: glError $error")
            throw RuntimeException("$op: glError $error")
        }
    }

    private fun initGL (side:Int) {

        /*======== Defining and storing the geometry ===========*/

        val verticesData = floatArrayOf(
                -1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,
                -1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,
                1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,
                1.0f,1.0f,0.0f
        )

        val indicesData = shortArrayOf(0,1,2,0,3,2)

        val vertexBuffer : FloatBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(verticesData.size * 4)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer()
        vertexBuffer.put(verticesData).position(0)

        val indexBuffer : ShortBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indicesData.size * 2).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            .asShortBuffer()
        indexBuffer.put(indicesData).position(0)

        val buffers = IntArray(2)
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(2, buffers, 0)
        val vbo = buffers[0]
        val ibo = buffers[1]

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            vertexBuffer.capacity() * 4, // 4 = bytes per float
            vertexBuffer,
            GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo)
        GLES20.glBufferData(
            GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            indexBuffer.capacity() * 2, // 2 = bytes per short
            indexBuffer,
            GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)

        /*================ Shaders ====================*/

        // Vertex shader source code
        val vertCode =
        """
        attribute vec3 coordinates;

        void main(void) {
            gl_Position = vec4(coordinates, 1.0);
        }
        """

        //fragment shader source code
        val fragCode =
        """
        precision mediump float;

        // The texture.
        uniform sampler2D u_tex;

        void main(void) {
            vec4 color = texture2D(u_tex, vec2(gl_FragCoord.x/$side.0, gl_FragCoord.y/$side.0));
            gl_FragColor = color;
        }
        """

        // Create a shader program object to store
        // the combined shader program
        val shaderProgram = createProgram(vertCode, fragCode)

        // Use the combined shader program object
        GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram)

        /*======= Associating shaders to buffer objects =======*/

        // Bind vertex buffer object
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)

        // Bind index buffer object
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo)

        // Get the attribute location
        val coord = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "coordinates")

        // Point an attribute to the currently bound VBO
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0,0)

        // Enable the attribute
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(coord)
    }

    private fun updateGLCanvas (matrix : ByteArray, side : Int) {
        val textureImage = floatArrayOf(
            0f,0f,0f,
            1f,0f,0f,
            0f,0f,1f,
            1f,1f,0f
        )
        val textureImageBuffer : FloatBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureImage.size * 4)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer()
        textureImageBuffer.put(textureImage).position(0)

        val texArray = IntArray(1)
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1,texArray,0)
        val textureId = texArray[0]
        if (texArray[0]==0) Log.e(TAG, "Error with Texture!")
        else Log.e(TAG, "Texture id $textureId created!")

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0)
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId)

        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST)
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST)

        //TODO: Flip Y axis!!!
        //gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
        GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1)

        //gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, side, side, 0, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array(matrix));
        //TODO: change 2 to parameter 'side'
        GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GLES20.GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, textureImageBuffer)

        // Clear the canvas
        GLES20.glClearColor(1f,0.5f,0.5f,0.9f)

        // Enable the depth test
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST)

        // Clear the color buffer bit
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        // Set the view port
        //TODO: set proper canvas dimensions
        GLES20.glViewport(0,0,500,500)

        // Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0)
    }
```

Shaders compile and link without any error. Code runs without any problem, but the only thing showing is my pretty pink background. The test code should display my [2x2]pixel texture ... but for some reason it refuses to do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems this code had many flaws ... for some reason, openGL ES2 didn't like my element array buffer, so I ditched it.
Then

```
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GLES20.GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, textureImageBuffer)
```

turned out to be fine for the emulator, but on a real device using GLES20.GL_FLOAT caused a heartburn ... changing it to GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE solved the problem!